# Why have I been fatigued/exhausted for the past month?

Tags: sleep, diagnostics, fatigue

For the past month, I've been feeling extremely fatigued, exhausted, out of breath and even light headed! I know I've been sleeping as usual. I can't even bend over, lift things, I can even exercise without being out of breath!

My work is not labor intensive at all. This is really effecting my quality of life. I wake up in the morning and my whole body is just aching as if I ran a marathon. Someone point me to the right direction! I have a doctors appointment next week so I want somethings I should discuss with him about.

Comment: What is it that you are asking exactly: what questions should you ask your doctor when you have your appointment or you want a preliminary diagnosis over the internet? If it's the first, I'd say ask whatever health-related interests you, and ask your doctor to explain anything they said but you didn't understand. If it's the second, we can't make a diagnosis here, going to your doctor's appointment is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are over a hundred medical conditions with the symptoms you have described, so be aware for any new symptoms and tell him if they are any.

Keep in mind any changes that have occurred before development of your symptoms (e.g: Did you get a new pet?, Did you go travelling?).

One thing that you could ask your Doctor is about your vitamin D levels. We create [Vitamin D](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/Summerhealth/Pages/vitamin-D-sunlight.aspx) from sunlight. Deficiency is linked with [fatigue and exhaustion](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/tiredness-and-fatigue/Pages/winter-tiredness.aspx)

Get well soon.

Answer (score 0):

[Iron deficiency](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/iron-deficiency-anemia/basics/symptoms/con-20019327) or [dehydration](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/dehydration/basics/symptoms/con-20030056) can both make a person fatigued. Try drinking more water, and eating more [iron rich foods](http://www.webmd.com/diet/iron-rich-foods?page=1).

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Whether you are a doctor or not is not really crucial here, but reliable references to back up your answer are. They are the only way for the community to verify an answer regardless of the reader's background, which is why they are [strongly encouraged](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) and answers without them risk being deleted. You can always [edit] your answer to add some. For further information on health SE policies please take our [tour] or visit the [help]. Thanks!

Comment: I edited it to add sources.